# how to create a dynamic page like a blog home page in asp using c#

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

In my website I want to create a page where i want to display values and description stored in database like as different posts are displayed on a blog and by clicking over them we can open the post. Here I am adding a sample pic what I intended to get...[image]

I am using asp.net please suggest me some sample code for generation of such page.

Comment: Did you use google to find example projects or free templates?

Comment: You say asp.net.  Are you using webforms or MVC, they're quite different?

Comment: i am using webforms..

Comment: @ B.Yaylaci. No I find them a bit confusing and i don't Have enough time... plus I have to  be crystal clear how my project is working..

Answer (score 0):

Entity:

```
[Table("Content")]
public class ContentEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string SubTitle { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Home Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = retrieveNecessaryData()
    return View(model);
}
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
     var model = retrieveArticleById(id)
     return View(model)
}
```

Index view:

```
@model List<pathtowhereverentityis.ContentEntity>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    //Style these however
    @item.Title
    @Html.ActionLink("Link to article","Details","Home", new {id = item.Id},null)
}
```

This should get you started, content entity that is linked to the database. Home controller returns the index view with a model. Use a for each loop to iterate through the list and style each one however you like.
The action link will go to the the page where the content is.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
This code won't work out the box, it's just example code to get you going. If you're a beginner and need further help, feel free to ask

Comment: would you please guide me where to place these code blocks and how is it working..

Comment: To clarify, are you using webforms or MVC to do this? My answer is MVC based.

Comment: My answer would be no use then, Mine is mvc as you specified in your tag